# QlikView: Displaying Millions Label Instead of Thousands

Tags: qlikview

I am using QlikView. In the program I made a bar chart. For my expression I defined thousands, millions and billions labels. The chart is showing thousands label and corresponding numbers (which are larger), but I want it to show Millions label (smaller numbers). How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the Static Step size on the Axes tab you can force QlikView to use the abbreviation you want otherwise it will use its best fit algorithm.

So this:

[image]

Becomes this:

[image]

By doing this:

[image]